# Java Stack Functions Diffrernce

Tags: java, stack

I was trying to solve a light coding problem here: https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/

But I don't know why the code below are not identical:

```
public void pop() {
    // if (!minStack.isEmpty() && minStack.peek() == stack.peek()){
    //     minStack.pop();
    // }
    // stack.pop();
    int x = stack.pop();
    if (!minStack.isEmpty() && x == minStack.peek()) {
        minStack.pop();
    }
}
```

When I use the commented code, it goes wrong. Why is that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, first difference - what if `stack` is empty and `minStack` is also empty? Then the two pieces of code *clearly* don't do the same thing...

Comment: @JonSkeet If both `stack` and `minStack` are empty, won't that result in both blocks calling `stack.pop()` and throwing an exception?

Comment: @DarthAndroid: I'm now confused myself... let me try again :)

Comment: Ah - aside from anything else, what are the types of `stack` and `minStack`? If they're `Stack<Integer>`, then there's a difference between `x == minStack.peek()` and `minStack.peek() == stack.peek()` as the former compares `int` values, but the latter compares references.

Comment: They are Stack<Integer>

Comment: With regard to the question, I think there can be a much simpler way of doing it rather than using 2 stacks.. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness, Debosmit! I've read a solution using only one stack in the discussion. I just wonder why my initial solution didn't work.

Comment: I hope your issues have been solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had stacks of primitives, both should work because you would be comparing contents using the `==`.

I am assuming you have stack of type `Integer` in which case the `==` checks for reference equality while you should check for `value equality`. Using a `.equals()` might just solve your problem. :)

Comment: Precisely. I just wrote up [`this working solution`](https://github.com/dray92/Programming-Questions/blob/master/leetcode/Min_Stack.java) that does not depend on using 2 stacks. I think it is a cleaner alternative.